Why won't my White Chocolate Ganache set in the freezer?
I melted my white chocolate per the truffle recipe: 4oz wafers (wilton), 1/4 cup cream.  I put it in the freezer to set but after 8 hours it still had not set, per instructions I retempered and added more chopped wafers stirring until the new chocolate was melted. Returned to the freezer, waited another 8 hours but it still has not set up. Does anyone have any advice?

See White chocolate ganache won't set. Also answered by rumtscho nearly 12 years ago!

This question is similar to: White chocolate ganache won't set. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Wilton wafers don't contain any cocoa butter and so cannot be "tempered". If you continue to use Wiltons, you can skip the tempering step in future batches.

Does the freezer step add enough variation that this can be considered a different question than the older white chocolate ganache question, or is this indeed a duplicate? What about Wilton wafers vs. Nestle chips?

@Marti I think that it's the combination of freezer and using chocolate that makes them different. The OP in the older question is using cocoa butter instead of chocolate, which is quite unusual. It turns out that the answers are the same, but that's not a reason to close the questions as duplicates.

You have way too much liquid there. When working with white chocolate, you can only use rather small amounts of liquid. A proper ratio would be 14 to 18 ml of cream to 100 g of white chocolate, which works out to around 1/16 cup of cream per 4 ounces of chocolate.
Your recipe sounds quite dodgy. Not only does it give you the wrong ratio, but it also directs you to use a freezer, which will likely throw your chocolate out of temper. I would suggest finding better instructions.
You should be able to save this batch by adding around 12 more ounces of white chocolate, unless it has split by spending time in the freezer.

I don't have any better alternatives but note that if OP adds another 12 ounces of white chocolate they will end up with a little over half a kilogram of ganache. That is a lot. Think about what you will do with such a large batch before you prepare it.

Thank you all for the feedback, I did finally get it to work out by adding more chocolate. But putting it in the freezer in covered does not harm, just a quick set up.

@BarbaraForget chocolate only tempers in a very short temperature window (26ish °C to 32ish °C), and putting it in the freezer brings you out of that window too quickly. That said, Wilton wafers don't need to tempered, so freezing them is fine.

@Hovercouch any chocolate can distemper when exposed to the wrong temperature change. If you want to keep the wafers tempered, you have to treat them accordingly, and the freezer is not the place for that.

@rumtscho Wilton wafers aren't "chocolate": they don't have any cocoa solids or cocoa butter. Tempering depends on cocoa butter's unusual crystalline properties. Anything without that can't be tempered (or distempered).

@Hovercouch Wilton products are rare in Europe, so I have never had contact with Wilton wafers. The OP states that they're making a white chocolate ganache; if the Wilton wafers aren't chocolate, then this may be an even deeper problem, and they should go and use some actual white chocolate made from cocoa butter.
